# How can I convert a numeric field YYYYMM to a date field so that I can subtract 90 days and then format the new field YYMMN6. in sas?

Tags: input, sas, date-conversion

I have a date field that is numeric and displays as 201603 (CalendarYearMonth), for example.  I want to be able to subtract 90 days from this date so that the end date is 201512 (RetentionYearMonth).  I then need to reference the end date from another table.  When I try to join the tables based on this date, they don't match because 201512 is showing as 20424 in the original table and 20423 in the table I am trying to join.  Any idea why I would be getting two different values for 201512?

I tried the following:

```
DATA Quote2;
SET Quote;
YearMonth = INPUT(STRIP(PUT(CalendarYearMonth,6.))||'01',YYMMDD10.);
RetentionYearMonth = YearMonth - 90;
FORMAT RetentionYearMonth YYMMN6.;
RUN;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm confused.  Your code as written looks like it works to me:

```
37   DATA Quote2;
38   CalendarYearMonth=201603;
39   YearMonth = INPUT(STRIP(PUT(CalendarYearMonth,6.))||'01',YYMMDD10.);
40   RetentionYearMonth = YearMonth - 90;
41   put (CalendarYearMonth YearMonth RetentionYearMonth)(=);
42   put RetentionYearMonth 8.;
43   format YearMonth RetentionYearMonth mmddyy10.;
44   RUN;

CalendarYearMonth=201603 YearMonth=03/01/2016 RetentionYearMonth=12/02/2015
   20424
```

YearMonth is the SAS date for March 1, 2016.  RetentionYearMonth is the SAS date for December 2, 2015 (90 days before YearMonth).  The SAS date for December 2, 2015 is 20424.

Reading again, it looks like maybe you were hoping RetentionYearMonth would be the SAS date for December **1**, 2015?  If so, then you can't simply subtract 90 days.  But you could use INTNX function perhaps, e.g.:

```
53   DATA Quote2;
54   CalendarYearMonth=201603;
55   YearMonth = INPUT(STRIP(PUT(CalendarYearMonth,6.))||'01',YYMMDD10.);
56   RetentionYearMonth = intnx('month',YearMonth,-3);
57   put (CalendarYearMonth YearMonth RetentionYearMonth)(=);
58   put RetentionYearMonth 8.;
59   format YearMonth RetentionYearMonth mmddyy10.;
60   RUN;

CalendarYearMonth=201603 YearMonth=03/01/2016 RetentionYearMonth=12/01/2015
   20423
NOTE: The data set WORK.QUOTE2 has 1 observations and 3 variables.
```

Above, INTNX returns the SAS date for the start of the month that is 3 months before YearMonth.

Remember when you join tables, the stored values are used for the join, not the formatted values (unless you explicitly convert the SAS dates to text strings).

Answer (score 0):

You make your life harder in SAS when you use text to represent dates, except for the specific date representation of '01MAR16'd, where the d after the quotes indicates this is a date value. Now you don't need `INPUT(STRIP(PUT()))`.

Then you can use built in functions like `intnx` to increment or decrement by 90 days (or whatever other interval you want).

`data quote3;
    calendaryearmonth = '01MAR16'd;
    retentionyearmonth = intnx('day',calendaryearmonth,-90);
    format retentionyearmonth yymmn6.;
run;`

Also, I point out that your original data value in `calendaryearmonth` does not have a day of the month associated with it, it is simply 201603 and then you subtract 90 days from it, this is relatively undefined, although you can make it work, you could also run into unforeseen problems. I would think that just on a logical basis, this makes more sense to subtract 3 months, rather than 90 days. But that's more of a problem definition than a programming thing.

Comment: As I read the OP's code, they had a numeric variable CalendarYearMonth with the value 201603.  In order to get a SAS date, they converted it to character to append an '01' and then used input() to convert to SAS date before subtracting 90.  It doesn't subtract 90 from 201603.  Agree about subtracting 3 months via INTNX instead of 90 days, I think that's the cause of the problem.